# Concave to convex- shortest way from point to circle

Tags: matlab, convex, concave, cvx

I have the optimization problem. I need to find the shortest way from point inside the circle to circle's perimeter. The function of constrains is concave. To make it works, I need to change this concave function to convex. I looked for "Poles of Inaccessibility: A CalculationAlgorithm for the Remotest Placeson Earth" and triangulation, but couldn't find a working solutions. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Do you have to use CVX? What about good 'ol fashioned `fmincon` or `fminunc` from the Optimization Toolbox?

Comment: Yes i have to. University work, so u have to do with shitty tools instead of better ones.

Comment: Maybe I'm off here, but if some function, say `f:R->R`, is concave, then isn't `-f` convex? I know that a maximization problem with concave objective function, say `f`, is equivalent to the minimization problem over the convex function `-f`.